# Finding the category with highest proportion meeting a criterion in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, aggregate, dataframe

I have some [simple data](https://courses.edx.org/c4x/MITx/15.071x/asset/gerber.csv) of the form

```
>>> gerber.head()

  sex   yob  voting  hawthorne  civicduty  neighbors  self  control
0    0  1941       0          0          1          0     0        0
1    1  1947       0          0          1          0     0        0
2    1  1982       1          1          0          0     0        0
3    1  1950       1          1          0          0     0        0
4    0  1951       1          1          0          0     0        0
```

and would like to find the category (i.e. boolean valued column) with the highest proportion of voters (i.e. for which the proportion where `voting == 1` *within the category* is highest). I can do this with

```
gerber.groupby('voting').sum().apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()).iloc[1]
```

which produces a simple table

```
sex          0.309893
yob          0.315449
hawthorne    0.322375
civicduty    0.314538
neighbors    0.377948
self         0.345151
control      0.296638
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

that I can examine to give me what I want. This is the data I'm looking for, but there must be (a) a better way to express this using Python and Pandas, and (b) a way to return just the name of the category (here "neighbors").

How do I express this concisely in Python using Pandas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "category with the highest proportion of voters"?

Comment: @8one6: The proportion of 1s in each column; so here it's "neighbors".

Comment: How does that work for the `yob` column?

Comment: Ok.  See below for an answer in line with these comments.

Comment: Your solution (above) is going to be very strangely influenced by the `yob` column since it has such large numbers in it...are you comfortable that your exact code above gives the result you want when applied to the exact file you linked to?

Comment: @8one6: `yob` is not a "boolean valued column".

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this more directly by using mean. Also, I think that rather than do the groupby over every group then extract a row, I would use get_group to get the sub group where voting=1 and do the mean:

```
df1.groupby('voting').get_group(1).mean()
```

or to just get the neighbors:

```
df1.groupby('voting').get_group(1)['neighbors'].mean()
# equivalent: df1.groupby('voting')['neighbors'].get_group(1).mean()
```

To get the largest category use [idxmax](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
df1.groupby('voting').get_group(1).mean().idxmax()
```

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is this not it? Would help to have an example input for the desired output otherwise tricky to replicate!

Comment: The data is linked in the question. The output should be 'neighbors', based on the fact that 0.377948 > 0.345151 > 0.322375 > 0.314538 > 0.296638.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius oh, you're looking for idxmax so: `df1.groupby('voting').get_group(1).mean().idxmax()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
gerber = pd.read_csv('gerber.csv')
max(gerber[gerber.voting == 1].ix[:,3:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to think about your question for the `yob` column.  It sounds like you want to: look at rows where `voting==1` and then, among that data only, compute the fraction of `1`'s in the other columns (excluding `voting` itself and `yob`).  You then want to identify the column with the highest fraction.

I think this works:

```
gerber[gerber['voting']==1].mean().drop(['voting', 'yob']).argmax()
```

Comment: Sorry I was pretty unclear: "category" in one of the boolean valued columns. And what I'm looking for is which category has the highest proportion of 1s (i.e., for each category, calculating the proportion of that category that are 1s). My code does this, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer what I'm looking for (I hope). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Commented above...it sounds like you're now asking: restricting just to rows where `voting==1`, which other column contains the highest proportion of the `1`'s that are in the other columns.  Is that right?  How would you like to treat the `yob` column when answering that question.  Its data is distinctly different from that of your other columns.